# Creating a RESTful api using google cloud platform and Jersey

Tags: java, api, rest, jersey, jax-rs

Im currently trying to build a RESTful api using Jersey and google cloud platform.

I have deployed the application and following this link I can access it fine

http://2-dot-{application-id}.appspot.com/api/staff

However whenever I try to access the sql database stored there I have problems

I can access the database using sequel pro fine but whenever I try to code a solution to access it I get various errors, these include:

```
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor aroundWriteTo: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class java.util.ArrayList, genericType=java.util.ArrayList<com.staff.webservice.models.StaffInfo>.
```

This is my code to access the database so far, as I have removed previous code out of frustration and now cant get it back

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import com.google.appengine.api.utils.SystemProperty;

public class StaffDAO implements Staff{
public ArrayList<StaffInfo> getAllStaff() {

    ArrayList<StaffInfo> staffArray = new ArrayList<>();

    Connection connection = null;

    try {
        // Load the JDBC driver
        String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"; // MySQL MM JDBC driver
        Class.forName(driverName);

        // Create a connection to the database

        String url = "jdbc:google:mysql://{application-id}:staff-database?user={username}";
        String username = "{username}";
        String password = "{password}";
        String databaseName = "staff-database";
        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver";


        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

        System.out.println(connection.toString());




    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // Could not find the database driver
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // Could not connect to the database
    } 


    return staffArray;
}
}
```

How can I connect to the database and query it to retrieve data and post data to the database.

Answer (score 0):

I looks like the error is related to the result type of the method not being serializable to JSON, ie. not related to the database at all.